# Iterating through nested arrays with hyphen in object name

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, iterator

First of all, I know naming array objects with hyphens is completely incorrect, and I'm not the creator of this. I need to call an API within a service, and many objects are named improperly, like `{"children-education": [` and `{ "Kid Stories": [`.

I have tried assigning the name to a variable like `let edChild = "child-education"`and then parsing it to an object, like `edChild = JSON.parse(edChild)`to no avail. I really have no idea of what I'm doing, nor even if it's possible to do so.

I kinda have the option to call my customer and kindly ask his team to rename the objects to something less... stupid than special characters than I can't possible call in Typescript, but I'd like to learn if there's a way to surpass this in future occasions or if they can't rename it.

Here's an example of the JSON I'm trying to iterate through:

```
{
    "business":
    [
        {
            "anim":
            [
                {
                    "child-education": [
                        {
                            "Kid Stories": [

                                {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "Three Little Pinkies",
                                    "url": "#",
                                    "description": "shows how the world is beautiful"
                                },
                  (... and so on)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically is the problem with the hyphens?

Comment: By 'iterating", do you mean "accessing the value of a property"? `foo.bar` can be written `foo['bar']` in JavaScript (and TypeScript). That's (probably) what you need to do here: `someObject['child-education']`

Comment: I can't do this: `let showContent = this.arrayCont.business[0].anim[0].child-education[0].kid stories[0]`. Typescript throws an error and says that it can't find name 'education'.

Comment: Just do it like in my answer. @major

Comment: No, but you can use brackets: `obj['child-education']`. Probably a better option than telling your client something is impossible and stupid that isn't.

Comment: Managed it using `(...)anim[0]['child-education'][0]['Kid Stories'][0]`. Thank all for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse that JSON string like any JSON string, using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
let str = "{\n" +
  "    \"business\":\n" +
  "    [\n" +
  "        {\n" +
  "            \"anim\":\n" +
  "            [\n" +
  "                {\n" +
  "                    \"child-education\": [\n" +
  "                        {\n" +
  "                            \"Kid Stories\": [\n" +
  "\n" +
  "                                {\n" +
  "                                    \"id\": 1,\n" +
  "                                    \"name\": \"Three Little Pinkies\",\n" +
  "                                    \"url\": \"#\",\n" +
  "                                    \"description\": \"shows how the world is beautiful\"\n" +
  "                                }]}]}]}]}" +
  ""
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

After that, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access any property names

```js
let str = "{\n" +
  "    \"business\":\n" +
  "    [\n" +
  "        {\n" +
  "            \"anim\":\n" +
  "            [\n" +
  "                {\n" +
  "                    \"child-education\": [\n" +
  "                        {\n" +
  "                            \"Kid Stories\": [\n" +
  "\n" +
  "                                {\n" +
  "                                    \"id\": 1,\n" +
  "                                    \"name\": \"Three Little Pinkies\",\n" +
  "                                    \"url\": \"#\",\n" +
  "                                    \"description\": \"shows how the world is beautiful\"\n" +
  "                                }]}]}]}]}" +
  ""
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj.business[0].anim[0]['child-education'][0]['Kid Stories'][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. This JSON is already parsed in the API, so there's no need to stringify it and then parse it again. My only issue is trying to access the nested arrays with hyphens and spaces.

Comment: Cool. Then don't parse it. @major The rest is already explained in the answer as well